# QT5 + Pytest - Redirect console output to a widget, end up redirecting only part of the data

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a simple application that use pyQT5, to make an interface that include a textfield to output the results of tests, and a button, which call a test script via pytest.

So far, I am able to redirect part of the output, so I can print it in the textfield, but I do not understand clearly how does the redirect process works, because some things are print in my widget, some are print in the console output of pycharm (but it is the same if I run the app via terminal on OSX), and other print statement never get printed in either place.

This is an overview of my setup

mainfile.py (the one that contain the PyQT5 code to show the UI; omitting the extras, since it is a simple PyQT view with a button and a QTBrowserview)

```
class app(QMainWindow):

    @pyqtSlot();
    def button_run_test_click():
        self.run_the_test()
        print("clicked the button")

    def run_the_test(self):
        results = testclass.execute_test()
        print("ran tests")
        # print in the textBrowser the output
        self.textBrowserOutput.append(results.upper())

class testclass:

    @staticmethod
    def execute_test():
        try:
            console_output = sys.stdout


     sys.stdout = StringIO()
        # here you pass the parameters for Pytest; for sake of simplicity
        # I am just adding the test script name)
        pytest.main("mytest.py")
        console = sys.stdout.getvalue()
        sys.stdout.close()
        sys.stdout = console_output
        return console
```

The `mytest.py` is a simple file with one class, which is derived by Unittest class. There is a setup, teardown and test functions, so nothing exotic.

When I push the button; most of the print statements in the `mytest.py`, are not printed anywhere. I just get the output of pytest (the summary saying that pytest ran, the passed tests and eventual warning; if there are failures, I get the whole strack trace for each failure).

I am not sure why all the other statements are not saved in my `out` object. Same goes for the regular pytest output when it run the tests: it should print data, and print a dot if the test pass, and a `F` if the test fail; while I get nothing.

On top of that, I would like to get the output in realtime, but with my code, I just get the chunk once everything has been completed; not sure how to achieve that either. Any pointer would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: You mean for the test? This happen independently from the content of the test file. I can post here one that does a loop to waste time, and print out some strings, if that may help. My assumption is that there is something missing at conceptual level; which is why I didn't post anything that is not obvious, like how to run a PyQt form or a unit test file. Thanks

Comment: I asked you a [mcve] because I test your example with a trivial test and it worked, so maybe the problem is caused by something that depends on the test, so I ask you to show me your example in particular, maybe I chose an easy test . ;)

Comment: I see; so it works fine for you; this is unexpected. I thought the problem was related to how did I set up the output for the stdout; but it seems that there is something else going on. Updating the question with a minimal working example as soon as I can. Thanks!